# Need to query count in Mysql based on date intervals

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, mysql-workbench

I need to display a Line graph in Morris js chart. I'm currently displaying data of a week starting from current date and Mysql query I use is

```
select count(*) from jobs  where corp_id = '.$this->user->corp_id.' and DATE(created_at)  = DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -0 DAY) and job_status = 0 limit 1
select count(*) from jobs  where corp_id = '.$this->user->corp_id.' and DATE(created_at)  = DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) and job_status = 0 limit 1
```

I'm currently writing multiple queries iterating the query manually by changing the INTERVAL -0 DAY to 1,2,3,4 and so on and pushing them into single result set.I'm displaying the dates on X-Axis in my page by giving the x-axis values myself to the morris js code. I use PHP for it. Now I need to upgrade my chart with more visibility by changing time period.

[image: Result needed like this]

Is there any way to get the data and by toggling through the tabs like this the data must be changed according to the time selected. Even I need a way if its possible to add the dates along with the result of my query so the x axis would be dynamically populated from back end values itself.

I'm using PHP Laravel framework with MySql as Database. Even a Laravel query is also good.

tried this query using interval value 30(for month)

```
select count(*), DATE(created_at) from jobs where corp_id = 37 and DATE(created_at)  >= DATE_ADD(current_date(), INTERVAL -30 DAY) and job_status =0 group by DATE(created_at);
```

and got this
[image]

but I should also get dates which are not having result to show 0 count with respective date.

Comment: From looking at your array, you have a string of JSON at key 0, not a multi-dimensional array. You need to json_decode the string in order to reference it as an array. Not the full answer, but that is problem number 1.